# How to not print whole index if given number not found in table

Tags: java

I got this script to find given number from table and print number and index.

I'm having problem with number that are not in the table. I should print "number is not found" etc. and I tried with else, but not working. Any suggestions what to do with this?

with it prints whole table index.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EtsitynAlkionIndeksi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] taulukko = new int[10];
        taulukko[0] = 6;
        taulukko[1] = 2;
        taulukko[2] = 8;
        taulukko[3] = 1;
        taulukko[4] = 3;
        taulukko[5] = 0;
        taulukko[6] = 9;
        taulukko[7] = 7;

        System.out.print("Mitä etsitään? ");
        int etsittava = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        // Toteuta etsimistoiminnallisuus tänne
        int indeksi = 0;

        while (indeksi < taulukko.length) {
            int arvo = taulukko[indeksi];
            int eiLoydy = 0;

            if (etsittava == arvo) {
                System.out.println("Luku " + etsittava + " löytyy indeksistä " + indeksi + ".");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Ei löydy " + eiLoydy);
            }

            indeksi++;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EtsitynAlkionIndeksi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner lukija = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] taulukko = new int[10];
        taulukko[0] = 6;
        taulukko[1] = 2;
        taulukko[2] = 8;
        taulukko[3] = 1;
        taulukko[4] = 3;
        taulukko[5] = 0;
        taulukko[6] = 9;
        taulukko[7] = 7;

        System.out.print("Mitä etsitään? ");
        int etsittava = Integer.valueOf(lukija.nextLine());

        // Toteuta etsimistoiminnallisuus tänne
        int indeksi = 0;
        while (indeksi < taulukko.length) {
            int arvo = taulukko[indeksi];

            if (etsittava == arvo) {
                System.out.println("Luku " + etsittava + " löytyy indeksistä " + indeksi + ".");
                break;
            }
            indeksi++;
        }
        if (indeksi == taulukko.length) {
            System.out.println("Ei löydy ");
        }
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Mitä etsitään? 3
Luku 3 löytyy indeksistä 4.
```

The statement, `break;` forces the loop to terminate. Also, note that I have moved `System.out.println("Ei löydy " + eiLoydy);` outside the `while` loop with the condition, `if (indeksi == taulukko.length)` i.e. if the value of `indeksi` has reached a value equal to `taulukko.length`, it means that the loop has not been terminated prematurely concluding that the lookup value has not been found.